# Generating random numbers in range until a max for that number has been met in python

Tags: python, random, sequence

I'm trying to do something basic - use range 0-4 and generate a 36 number sequence such that each value is generated 9 times.

The var trial_init is just an array of 36 zeros.

I have generated:

```
trial_seq = []

for i in range(len(trial_init)-1):    
    while True:
        trial_val = random.choice(range(4))
        if (trial_seq.count(0) <=9 and trial_seq.count(1) <=9 and trial_seq.count(2) <=9 and trial_seq.count(3) <=9):
            break
    trial_seq.append(trial_val)
```

I guess I'm not sure exactly why it doesn't work.

It should generate a number 0, 1, 2 or 3 and to the extent that number has not been included in the trial_seq array more than 9 times, it should add it to the trial_seq array, otherwise it should generate another number, until 36 numbers have been generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is python.

You could actually go the other way around: generate an index set, and randomly assign indices from that to each of the four possible values:

```
trial_seq = [0]*36
indices = range(36)
random.shuffle(indices)
for i in range(36):
    trial_seq[indices[i]] = i % 4;
```

**EDIT**: Oh man, at times I'm stupid:

```
trial_seq = [ i % 4 for i in xrange(36) ]
random.shuffle(trial_seq)
```

does the same.

Comment: @bsils: added much better solution.

Comment: Got it! Motivating me to reduce lines in other code too. Gratzi!

Comment: how about `trial_seq = 9 * list(range(4))`

Comment: That generates the 4 number sequence in order, I was looking for as random as possible of a sequence with the caveat that no one value could appear more than 9 times. It's just a simple method to generate random trials under that constraint.

Comment: AnttiHaapala was just referring on how to create the list **before** shuffling it, @bsils; so the complete code would be `trial_seq = 9 * list(range(4))`    `random.shuffle(trial_seq)`. I find that pretty obvious...